# Not seeing custom Product Attribute in Images Tab

Tags: admin, attributes, product-attribute

So I created a custom attribute to be used on every product, and it's called product_detail_image (the client will upload a macro photo of the fabric).

Here is how my attribute is setup:

[image]

But I'm not seeing this show up in the Images tab on the product edit page.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Catalog -> Manage Attribute Sets, select an attribute set, that is assigned to required product and check if the attribute is assigned to group 'Images'.
If there is no attribute in 'Unassigned', then try to clean cache and rebuild indexes

Comment: There is no attribute set called 'Images'.

Comment: By default you have got only attribute set Default, go to this set and check

Comment: So I see 'Images' under groups, but I'm not seeing `product_detail_image` under Unassigned Attributes.

Comment: Try to clean cache and rebuilt indexes